# iPhone TableView When Scrolling Loses User Selection

Tags: iphone

I am using table view in my app, the task is multiple deletion of cells like iPhone message application. My problem is when select the cells check box and scroll the table then selected cells check marks are deselect. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll the table then its reload function automatically called. Thats why your selection have cleared. do one thing when you checked your check boxes then stores that values in an array after that call an custom reload function and in that reload your all values in your table...

Answer (score 0):

You need to Manage an array which contain the indexes of the rows for which you select a checkbox.

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method check whether the row index is in your index array show the checked image otherwise show unchecked image.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView will reuse your tableviewcell, that means it will never keep many cell object, just 5~6 cell maybe. It will save a lot of memory, but it may not keep the state you have set. So you must keep the data by yourself and assign to the cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```